# Unable to Install RJava in Eclipse

Tags: java, r

I have gone through 
http://www.codophile.com/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rjava/
to install RJava package..
i have an error each and evey time in Eclipse

**Error**: Cannot find JRI native library!
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.

**what i have to do?**
**Please give me needful answer as soon as possible..**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974392/setting-up-java-r-interface-jri-on-windows

Comment: http://www.studytrails.com/RJava-Eclipse-Plugin/

Comment: There's also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515624/rjava-error-when-running-with-eclipse 
I have no experience in integrating R and rJava in eclipse, even less on Windows systems, but I believe that with some research it shouldn't be too difficult to solve the problem.